# SQL sum case when between max date from table column

Tags: sql, sum, max, case-when

I am trying to sum in SQL cases when a date is between a max date minus 7 and a max date, but unable to get it right.

Example:
sum(case when *date* between max(*date from field*)-7 and max(*date from field*) then *column to sum* else 0 end) as '0-7 Days'

Comment: I think you need two passes or a subquery, otherwise, how do you know the MAX(date)? If your DB supports CTE, this should set up easily. Which DB are you using.

Comment: It would be helpful, if you can share some sample data and database and its version.

Answer (score 1):

```
This may work:
```

I may be getting the DATEDIFFs a little bit confused but it should be something along those lines

```
SUM(CASE
    WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,datecolumn,DATEADD(DAY,-7,max(datecolumn)))<0 AND DATEDIFF(DAY,datecolumn,max(datecolumn))>0
    THEN columntosum
    ELSE 0 
    END) AS '0-7 Days'
```

Answer (score 1):

In most databases, you can do something like this:

```
select (case when datecol >= maxdatecol - 7 and datecol <= maxdatecol then columntosum else 0
        end) as days_0_7
from (select t.*,
             max(datecol) over () as maxdatecol
      from table t
     ) t;
```

Note that date arithmetic varies between databases, so this exact syntax may not work (small modifications should fix the problems for most databases).